# Airflow deprecation warning Invalid arguments were passed

Tags: airflow

I have the following code on Airflow 1.9:

```
import_op = MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='import',
    mysql_conn_id='oproduction',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='gcpm',
    provide_context=True,
    approx_max_file_size_bytes = 100000000, #100MB per file
    sql = 'import.sql',
    params={'next_to_import': NEXT_TO_IMPORT, 'table_name' : TABLE_NAME},
    bucket=GCS_BUCKET_ID,
    filename=file_name_orders,
    dag=dag)
```

Why does it genereates:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/airflow/models.py:2160:
>   PendingDeprecationWarning: Invalid arguments were passed to
>   MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator. Support for passing such arguments
>   will be dropped in Airflow 2.0. Invalid arguments were:
>   *args: ()
>   **kwargs: {'provide_context': True}   category=PendingDeprecationWarning

What is the problem with the `provide_context`? To the best of my knowledge it is needed for the usage of `params`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`provide_context` is not needed for `params`.

`params` parameter (`dict` type) can be passed to any Operator.

You would mostly use `provide_context` with `PythonOperator`, `BranchPythonOperator`. A good example is https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/operator.html#pythonoperator.

`MySqlToGoogleCloudStorageOperator` has no parameter `provide_context`, hence it is passed in `**kwargs` and you get Deprecation warning.

If you check docstring of `PythonOperator` for `provide_context` :

> if set to true, Airflow will pass a set of keyword arguments that can
>   be used in your function. This set of kwargs correspond exactly to
>   what you can use in your jinja templates. For this to work, you need
>   to define `**kwargs` in your function header.

It has the following code if you check the source code:

```py
if self.provide_context:
            context.update(self.op_kwargs)
            context['templates_dict'] = self.templates_dict
            self.op_kwargs = context
```

So in simple terms, it passes the following dictionary with `templates_dict` to your function pass in `python_callable`:

```py
{
    'END_DATE': ds,
    'conf': configuration,
    'dag': task.dag,
    'dag_run': dag_run,
    'ds': ds,
    'ds_nodash': ds_nodash,
    'end_date': ds,
    'execution_date': self.execution_date,
    'latest_date': ds,
    'macros': macros,
    'params': params,
    'run_id': run_id,
    'tables': tables,
    'task': task,
    'task_instance': self,
    'task_instance_key_str': ti_key_str,
    'test_mode': self.test_mode,
    'ti': self,
    'tomorrow_ds': tomorrow_ds,
    'tomorrow_ds_nodash': tomorrow_ds_nodash,
    'ts': ts,
    'ts_nodash': ts_nodash,
    'yesterday_ds': yesterday_ds,
    'yesterday_ds_nodash': yesterday_ds_nodash,
}
```

So this can be used in the function as follows:

```py
def print_context(ds, **kwargs):
    pprint(kwargs)
    ti = context['task_instance']
    exec_date = context['execution_date']
    print(ds)
    return 'Whatever you return gets printed in the logs'


run_this = PythonOperator(
    task_id='print_the_context',
    provide_context=True,
    python_callable=print_context,
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: OK. So can you please explain why  provide_context is even needed? provide_context will always be true when params is added for PythonOperator. It seems like a parameter that Airflow can figure out it's value by it's own... It gives nothing to ask the user to specify it

Comment: You would use `provide_context` so that it passes the variables to the function passed in `python_callable` in `PythonOperator`